# Getting Error when Passing the TableName with Parameters using -Android Sqlite Room ORM

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

1.when trying to access the data with tablename as a parameter using method, getting below mentioned error using Room Library in android.

**-->  There is a problem with the query: ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: table Name)**

**MainActivity.class**

```
userData1= userSampleDatabase.daoAccessForUser().getItembyIdvalue("UserData","1");
```

**DaoAccessForUser.class**

```
 @Query("select * from 'tableName' where id = :id")
 List<UserData> getItembyIdvalue(String tableName,String id);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: tableName is your name of table ?

Comment: ya in this method getItembyIdvalue("UserData","1"); iam passing tablename as "UserData"

Comment: try this `@Query("select * from "+tableName+" where id = :id")` @Kumar

Comment: try this  `@Query("select * from ENTITY :tableName  where id = :id")`

Comment: @SantanuSur show this error <join operator>, <table alias>, AS, GROUP, INDEXED, LIMIT, NOT, ORDER, WHERE, comma or semicolon expected, got ':tableName'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Room does not support dynamic replacement of the table name.

In your DAO, replace `'tableName'` with the actual table name, as defined on the associated `@Entity`. Or, [use `@RawQuery`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RawQuery.html) instead of `@Query` and provide the entire SQL `SELECT` statement at runtime.

Comment: hi, its showing-  @RawQuery cannot resolve symbol :-(

Comment: can you u help me how to import @RawQuery in gradle

Comment: @Kumar: I think that's in the 1.1.0 alpha release.

Answer (score 1):

There is a reason why you get this error at compile time; **Room** check queries at **compile** time to ensure your application won't run into problem in **runtime**..

So as far as **Room** knows there may be no `id` in your `table` at all! To prevent your app from encountering such a problem room require you to provide `table` name beforehand. If this feature is essential to your project try using **ORMs** with `Query Builder` like **greenDAO** or **dbflow**

Hope you understand Room behaviour ^^

Answer (score 1):

as CommonsWare suggested you can use @RawQuery
In you **DaoAccessForUser.class**

```
@RawQuery
 List<UserData> getUserDataList(String query);
```

and you can call it like this

```
String tablename="UserData";
String id="1";
    userData1= userSampleDatabase.daoAccessForUser().getUserDataList("select * from "+tablename+" where id = " + id);
```